# How did this girl interpret this sentence?

Tags: meaning, interpretation

Unsure of how Girl 2 (bold line) interpreted what was said by Girl 1. The reader learns shortly after that 鈴木 and 高橋 were both part of the same group, and in similar positions(いじられキャラ）.

Looking at the exchange below we can see Girl 1 clarify what actually happened which clearly wasn't what Girl 2 was expecting. I understand what Girl 2 is literally saying by 'キャラかぶってんもんねー' but I don't understand what she is implying that would lead to this happening(or her understanding of what happened).

Girl 1「ねえねえ、知ってる？　鈴木ってあのグループからハブられたらしいよ」

Girl 2「え、マジで？」

Girl 2「鈴木、あそこのリーダーから結構かわいがられたじゃん。何かマズったの？」

Girl 1「高橋を庇って対立しちゃったみたい」

Girl 2 **「あー、キャラかぶってんもんねー、あるある」**

Girl 1「いやそうじゃなくてさ、高橋が嫌がってると思ってマジギレかましちゃったんだって」

Girl 2「あ、そっちなんだ。それはまずいっしょー」

Comment: can you provide the context or from where did you site this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case you've missed something, this 被る means "to overlap" or "to be similar", and キャラ被ってる seems to refer to the fact that 鈴木 and 高橋 are both いじられキャラ in the group.

However, I'm not sure how キャラ被ってる can work as the reason for 高橋を庇って対立しちゃった in the given context, either. Maybe Girl 2 thought "Because 鈴木 is an いじられキャラ herself, she wanted to protect 高橋's position as an いじられキャラ"? This sounds weird to me... Understanding the broader context may solve the problem, but it's probably beyond the scope of this site.